# Getting error over the calculation on retrieved data from Fire base

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm going to calculate the average rating of books.

Here,Rating and Counter is initialized in Firebase. I am getting fatal error on this line of my code `sum = Double.parseDouble(r);` which is

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference

But I could not find out the reason. It accurately retrieves both the counter value and rating without the rating calculation portion.

Here's the code and the database snapshot.

[image]

```
            public class GetReview {
                private FirebaseUser user;
                private Firebase mrootref;
                private String path2="hhhh";
                private String c;
                private String r;
                private Double sum;
               // private String rate = " ";
                private Double avg;
                private Double counter;
                private Double rate;
                private double rounded;


                GetReview()
                {
                    user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                    Log.d("path1", path2);
                    path2= myCategory.getPath();
                    Log.d("paths", path2);

                };

                public void setReview(String bookname, Double rating) {

                    rate= rating;
                    //sum = sum+rate;
                    Log.d("sum?", rating.toString());

                    path2 += "/"+bookname+"/";
                    mrootref = new Firebase(path2);

                   mrootref.addValueEventListener(new com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onDataChange(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                           for (com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot mshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                           {
                               Log.d("emmaList ", mshot.toString());

                               //Map<String, String> mmap = mshot.getValue(Map.class);
                               // c = mshot.child("Counter:").getValue().toString();
                               //String review = mshot.getKey().toString();
                               //String emma = mshot.getKey().toString();
                               //Log.d(review, "I am the key");
                               if (mshot.getKey().toString().equals("Counter")) {

                                   c =String.valueOf( mshot.getValue());
                                   Log.d(c, "I am counter");
                               }
                               if (mshot.getKey().toString().equals("Rating")) {
                                   r =String.valueOf( mshot.getValue());
                                   Log.d(r, "I am rate");

                               }
                               //r = mmap.get("Rating");
                               counter = Double.parseDouble(c);
                               counter++;
                               sum = Double.parseDouble(r);
                               sum = sum + rate;
                               avg = sum / counter;
                               sum = avg;
                               Log.d(counter.toString(), "i am review");
                               //Log.d(  avg.toString(),"i am avg");
                               BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(avg);
                               bd = bd.round(new MathContext(3));
                               rounded = bd.doubleValue();
                               //Map revBook = new HashMap();
                               mrootref.child("Counter").setValue(counter.toString());
                               mrootref.child("Rating").setValue(Double.toString(rounded));


                           }
                       }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                            //Toast.makeText(GetReview.this, "Error in data retrieval", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
                });
            }
            }
```

Comment: what it prints.. `Log.d("emmaList ", mshot.toString());`. cuz your `r` variable's value is null.

Comment: It only prints the counter value D/emmaList: DataSnapshot { key = Counter, value = 0 } But no Rating value.

Comment: actually you are looping over data nodes of list.. try to put the code(that you wrote inside after the if statements) outside of for loop..

Comment: It shows garbage value